# Change a text box's value continuously as a HTML5 range slider moves

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a pair of inputs that are text and range types respectively

```
<input type=range min=100 max=100000 val=1000 step=1000 id=priceSliderMin></input>`
<input type=text id=priceTextMin></input>
```

I also have a pair of jQuery functions that update the partner input as the other changes.

```
$('#priceSliderMin').change(function(event){
$('#priceTextMin').prop('value', parseInt($('#priceSliderMin').prop('value')));
});
$('#priceTextMin').keyup(function(event){
$('#priceSliderMin').prop('value', parseInt($('#priceTextMin').prop('value')))
})
```

The problem is that the slider doesn't update the text field until I release the mouse button. Is there a way I could update it as it moves? I found an [example](http://demosthenes.info/blog/757/Playing-With-The-HTML5-range-Slider-Input) using raw JavaScript that seems to work, but I can't replicate it with jQuery, even when using Chrome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you view the source of that page with the example, they are actually using `oninput` to listen to the changes while dragging (the posted source code shows `onchange`, which doesn't trigger until dragging is complete). To do this in jQuery, try this...

```
$('#priceSliderMin').on('input', function(){
    $('#priceTextMin').val($('#priceSliderMin').val());
});
```

[**Demo - Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SXABv/)

Comment: Deceptive example! Thank you for making the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your jquery functions in document.ready like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#priceSliderMin').change(function(event){
    $('#priceTextMin').prop('value', parseInt($('#priceSliderMin').prop('value')));
});
    $('#priceTextMin').keyup(function(event){
    $('#priceSliderMin').prop('value', parseInt($('#priceTextMin').prop('value')))
})
});
```

Its just a thought... Best of luck

Comment: My fault for not mentioning this, but the elements are inserted dynamically, and all the changes to them are done within a document.ready block like you suggested. Thanks though, reinforces good practices.

Answer (score 0):

You could use .mousmove()

```
$('#priceSliderMin').mousemove(function (){
    document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=this.value;
    //$("#range").html(newValue);
});
```

[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/34XCc/7/)

Comment: Don't use `mousemove`; input elements can also be changed with the arrow keys on your keyboard. Use `on('input', ...)` instead.